# Can I build a linux distro with libc instead of glibc

Tags: linux, compiling, glibc

I recently had a conversation with a friend who is a highly skill software engineer, and he showed me some articles outlining the fact libc was much better than glibc.

I wonder if its possible to use libc instead, and what kind of problems would I come up against if I went this route?

Comment: That's kinda meaningless; "libc" is not a single thing, it's a family (of which glibc is a member).  *Whose* libc?  FreeBSD's?

Comment: yeah i think he was being specific about freebsd when he was making the reference, my knowledge in this area is limited!

Comment: Quite meaningless is an understatement. He said it was "much better" in what way? Such statements are useless without elaboration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Context:  assuming from above comments that a BSDish `libc` is meant.

I think it's been looked into, but `libc` tends to be tightly tied to a given kernel (`glibc` has an abstraction layer, which allows it some portability but causes the usual problems that an abstraction layer causes) and making BSD `libc` work with a Linux kernel would require a near complete rewrite.  key system services are very different between the two systems (one example:  BSD `libc` assumes that there are no pipes/FIFOs, because BSD uses socketpairs instead; conversely, Linux doesn't support pipe-compatible socketpairs).

Going the other direction (Debian has an experimental Linux userspace on a FreeBSD kernel, I think) is possible due to `glibc`'s portability layer.

Answer (score 5):

There are many libc implementations. It is possible and quite commmon to build a system using [uClibc](http://www.uclibc.org/) or [EGLIBC](http://www.eglibc.org/home). It's not even particularly difficult: try [Buildroot](http://buildroot.net/).

Comment: fantastic recommendation, i am looking into this now

Comment: eglibc is virtually equivalent to glibc, for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Many software depends on `glibc` itself or `glibc` macroses or just `glibc` style so build fails. You can fix any software easy if you know `glibc` from inside. For example we can see here [linux headers](https://github.com/sabotage-linux/kernel-headers) for `musl`. Headers are not finished but you can checkout commits and see how this work looks like.

Every developer tests its software using `glibc` based system. It is not possible to fix all live software development and make it compatible with other `libc` using right solution like pull request. So general purpose systems like `gentoo` can't be build using alternative libc without infinite pain.

Embedded developers (from `openwrt` for example) are fixing software versions and making a heavy work around it. So embedded system (like `openwrt`) only can provide a [source](https://github.com/openwrt) that can be build with alternative libc like `musl` or `uclibc`.

The only painless and right way to replace `glibc` with other `libc` is to implement special wrapper that simulates all `glibc` behaviours using other `libc`. There is no such project today.